# how to pass WPF UI values to method on button click

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF UI that has 3 i/p controls, 2 dtp and 1 chk box, user will select some value and click search button.

How can I pass values from both dtPicker and chkBox on Button click to a method defined in viewModel?

On click on button, control is coming over to method in view model but how to pass those selected values in method?

Comment: 1. If all controls bind to properties on the same viewModel, just use the properties directly. 2. If they are on different viewModels, you can add a reference in the constructor of the viewmodel that has the button Command to the required viewmodels. 3. You can name the controls and databind the CommandParameter of the button to the required property of the required control.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass anything, simply set up the bindings correctly.

- DatePicker - `SelectedDate`
- CheckBox - `IsChecked`

Then you'll probably use RelayCommand or something like that and you'll have an easy access to the viewmodel properties.